# In which language we use to define a variable as $value = x

Tags: vb.net, scripting

I have to know what language is used here. In which language do we define a variable as $value = x
Does this language have loop controls? I need this information, can any one provide?

```
Public sub Annual_Leave()
      $Decimal_Output1 = 0    //variables
      $Decimal_Output2 = 0

    IF @ServiceMonths@ = 1 OR @ServiceMonths@ = 2 THEN
            $Decimal_Output1 = 0
        ELSEIF @ServiceMonths@ => 3 AND @ServiceMonths@ <= 12 THEN
        IF @ServiceMonths@ = 3 THEN
            $Decimal_Output1 = 1.7
     END IF
    ELSE
                  $Decimal_Output1 = 21
                  $Decimal_Output2 = 0
    END IF
    End sub
```

Comment: If you don't know the language, why do you tag vb.net?

Comment: I can only upvote the above comment, it is obviously VB syntax.

Comment: Then what about "Dim variable as datatype". I'm confused with the $ symbol

Comment: It's an alternative way for defining a datatype. Check this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/type-characters)

Comment: @David : Those are _suffixes_ that can be added instead of `As <datatype>`, the OP's variables are _prefixed_ with them. It would also mean that his `Decimal_Output#` variables are strings, which they obviously aren't. Besides, all variables in VB.NET must be declared with `Dim` or an access modifier. -- OP: This isn't valid VB.NET code, there are a few languages that have very similar syntax to VB/VB.NET, however I can't remember their names.

Comment: @Visual Vincent, you are right, I didn't noticed that detail